# HTTP-Server reachable via IP-Adress, but not via domain name

Tags: apache, docker, curl, networking, dns

First question on StackOverflow ever, thanks in advance for your help ;-)

So I just set up my first personal webserver and it is mostly working fine.

I have three services running:

1. **nginx** / **apache2** (dockerized) (Tried both, one at a time of course) on port 80
2. **teamspeak** (dockerized) on port 9987
3. **sshd** (*not* dockerized) on port 22

I *can* access all servers via IP-Address (Teamspeak Client / Curl / openSSH).

**Now the part I don't unterstand:** While I *can* connect to the *teamspeak* / *ssh* through the server's domain name `example.com`, I *cannot* connect to the http-Server through the domain name (Neither *curl* nor browser):

- `curl example.com`, `curl http://example.com`, `curl http://example.com:80`  *from my home machine* all yield no response from the server (only the eventual timeout).
- `curl example.com` *from the server itself* yields the nginx/apache example document (which is the expected result).

**Some more information:**

- `host example.com` from my home machine returns my server's ip.
- DNS Record for the domain name is: `Name: example.com; Type: A; TTL: 3600; Target: <server-ip>`
- I did not configure the http-servers in any way. Only used the official docker images.
- The result of `docker ps` on the server:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                        NAMES
ea9d7dc1fd72        c5a012f9cf45        "httpd-foreground"       4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                                                         httpd
1ce69dc63349        teamspeak           "entrypoint.sh ts3se…"   17 hours ago        Up 15 hours         0.0.0.0:10011->10011/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9987->9987/udp, 0.0.0.0:30033->30033/tcp   teamspeak
```

**Update:** Additional information as requested by @taleodor:

- The server is a root-server hosted at https://zap-hosting.com
- `dig example.com` shows the correct ip for my server like this:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.    2814    IN  A   <server-ip>
```

- Plain nginx shows the same behavior as the dockerized version

Comment: Hi @ctcq, please provide the following information: 

1. where is your server hosted?

2. what is `dig example.com` (replace example.com with your server uri) produce from your home machine - do you get correct ip?

3. did you check security groups, etc on your cloud provider - i.e. did you check non-dockerized way (say just install plain nginx and see if you can connect to that).